# Does $\int \tan^3x\sec^2x \space dx$ have 2 solutions?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

So normally, you evaluate $\int\tan^3x\sec^2x \space dx$ by substituting $u = \tan x$ and $du = \sec^2x\space dx$ right? So,
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\int\tan^3x\sec^2x \space dx &= \int u^3 \space du \\
  &= \frac{u^4}{4} + C\\
  &= \frac{tan^4x}{4} + C \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

But, I tried to solve it this way instead,
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\int\tan^3x\sec^2x \space dx &= \int\tan^2x\tan x\sec x\sec x\space dx \\
  &= \int(\sec^2x-1)\tan x\sec x\sec x\space dx \\
  &= \int\sec^3x\tan x\sec x-\sec x\tan x\sec x\space dx \\
  &= \int\sec^3x\tan x\sec x-\sec x\tan x\sec x\space dx \\
  &= \int\sec^3x\tan x\sec x\space dx - \int\sec x\tan x\sec x\space dx \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

and then substituting $u = \sec x$, thus $du = \tan x\sec x\space dx$. So,
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\int\sec^3x\tan x\sec x\space dx - \int\sec x\tan x\sec x\space dx &= \int u^3 du - \int u\space du\\
&= \frac{u^4}{4} - \frac{u^2}{2} + C \\
&= \frac{\sec^4x}{4} - \frac{\sec^2x}{2} + C \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

What?! Can someone explain to me where I made the mistake?

Comment: If you simplify the second using $\sec^2 x=\tan^2 x+1$, you'll get the first result.

Comment: @cosmo5 Yeah, but that kinda defeats the purpose of this alternate way. My question is, can you evaluate that using the second way? If not, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no mistake. Both methods resulted in the same solution, up to a constant of integration. Indeed, notice that:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{4}\tan^4 x + C
&= \frac{1}{4}(\tan^2 x)^2 + C \\
&= \frac{1}{4}(\sec^2 x - 1)^2 + C \\
&= \frac{1}{4}(\sec^4 x - 2\sec^2 x + 1) + C \\
&= \frac{1}{4}\sec^4 x - \frac{1}{2}\sec^2 x + \frac{1}{4} + C \\
&= \frac{1}{4}\sec^4 x - \frac{1}{2}\sec^2 x + D \\
\end{align*}

where $D = \frac{1}{4} + C$ is an arbitrary constant of integration.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: So how could 2 methods yield 2 slightly different results? Why didn't the second method get the exact same result as in the first method?

Comment: @Vinz This happens sometimes. The two seemingly different results only differ by a constant. Watch this video for another example: [integration of sinxcosx](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZB0IFCmtphE)

Comment: @Vinz One way to look at it is that, because these trigonometric functions behave differently at $x=0$, both solutions are of the form $f(x)+y_0$ with the same $f$ satisfying $f(0)=0$. The integration constant $y_0$ is then the value of an antiderivative of interest at $x=0$. In this case$$f(x)=\tfrac14\tan^4x,\,y_0=C=D-\tfrac14.$$

Comment: @Forester No way, I was never taught about this. So would $\frac{\sec^4x}{4} - \frac{\sec^2x}{2} + C$ be a valid answer then?

Comment: @Vinz: Since you clearly know that one should add $C$ when integrating, it seems very likely that someone must have taught you (probably right at the very beginning of your integration career) that two different antiderivatives of the same function (on the same interval) can only differ by a constant.

Comment: @Vinz Yes, it would be because the 2 functions differ only by a constant as shown in the answer.You may ask "Why will 2 differents answers of a definite integral which differ by a constant be considered the same?"This is a valid question.Think of integration as the reverse process of differentiation.If a function on differentiating gives the original function back then it is the indefinite integral of the original function since you are differentiating,does the constant matter?No because derivative of a constant is 0 anyways.Therefore both can be valid answers if they differ only by a constant